# PHP combines 2 arrays

Tags: php, arrays, json

I have 2 arrays in php

```
$array1[] = a,b,c,d,e;
$array2[] = 1,2,3,4,5;

$data = array('letter'=>$array1,'num'=>$array2);

return json_encode($data);
```

This will return:

```
[[a,b,c,d,e],[1,2,3,4,5]]
```

I'd like to return it in json_encode like this:

```
 $data = [[1a,1],[b,2],[c,3],[d,4],[e,5]];
```

Can someone help me with this?

Comment: how to do it @kmlnvm?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this is the simplest solution

```
$result = array();
foreach ($array1 as $k1 => $v1) {
    $result[] = array($v1, $array2[$k1]);
}
echo json_encode($result)
```

but arrays must have the same length and same keys

Comment: brute force but it answers the question.

Answer (score 0):

**Try below code,** it is flexible and don't have to care about the length of the arrays.

```
<?php
$letters = array('a','b','c','d','e');
$numbers = array('1','2','3','4','5');

$counter = (sizeof($letters) > sizeof($numbers)) ? sizeof($letters) : sizeof($numbers);

$arr = array();
for($i=0; $i<$counter; $i++)
{
    if(array_key_exists($i, $letters))
        $arr[$i][] = $letters[$i];

    if(array_key_exists($i, $numbers))
        $arr[$i][] = $numbers[$i];
}

$json = json_encode($arr);
echo $json;
```

**Output:**

```
[["a","1"],["b","2"],["c","3"],["d","4"],["e","5"]]
```

**Demo:**
http://3v4l.org/7v7X4

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is the function [array_combine()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-combine.php).

Here is an example:

```
$array1 = array("a","b","c","d","e");
$array2 = array(1,2,3,4,5);

$data = array_combine($array1, $array2);

$new_data = array();
foreach($data AS $key => $value) {
    $new_data[] = array($key, $value);
}

print_r(json_encode($new_data));
```

Which should return something like:

```
[["a",1],["b",2],["c",3],["d",4],["e",5]]
```

**UPDATE** Changed the code to give the result wanted...